# How to handle Cookie set without secure flag web scan result

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, cookies

A web scan I ran mentions that my web application has the following low risk Cookie set without secure flag:

> > Cookie set without secure flag

This is a .NET application written in ASP.NET Webforms.

I researched this and amended my web.config to include this in the  section:

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
```

And added this also inside the  section

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms requireSSL="true">
        <!-- forms content -->
    </forms>
</authentication>
```

However when I do this my cookies are not saved, the web application does not behave as expected. When I try and login to the application, the cookie is not created and the login page just refreshes.

I don't know much about SSL so I am not sure if the website needs to be built on https, or how I even go about that.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Secure flag on the cookie indicate a Cookie who is only sent in a HTTPS/SSL channel. 
If you're application is using HTTP, and you set Secure Flag, the cookie will not be sent by the browser and this could be you're problem